# Finding proper involutions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let
$π = (LRN)(AUM)(BCG)(TXY)(KDFQVEO)(HJPSWIZ)  $
I'm looking to find 4 distinct proper involutions

I write the scheme,
$(LRN)(BCG)(KDFQVEO)$
$(AUM)(TXY)(HJPSWIZ)$

Then compute tau and sigma and I have
$τ = (LA)(RU)(NM)(BT)(CX)(GY)(KH)(DJ)(FP)(QS)(VW)(EI)(OZ) $ 
$σ= (RA)(NU)(LM)(CT)(GX)(BY)(DH)(FJ)(QP)(VS)(EW)(OI)(KZ)$

Now I'm confused How I find another τ, σ..
I was told to shift the lower cycles, but I have no idea what that means?
Can someone explain to me how exactly I can "Shift the lower cycles" to find
another proper involution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that you already have is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (LRN)\color{blue}{(BCG)}(KDFQVEO)   \\
 (AUM)\color{blue}{(TXY)}(HJPSWIZ) 
\end{eqnarray*}
leading to tau and sigma
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tau   = (LA)(RU)(NM)\color{blue}{(BT)(CX)(GY)}(KH)(DJ)(FP)(QS)(VW)(EI)(OZ) \\
\sigma = (RA)(NU)(LM)\color{blue}{(CT)(GX)(BY)}(DH)(FJ)(QP)(VS)(EW)(OI)(KZ)
\end{eqnarray*}

Another two solutions can be generated by the same procedure by permuting the $3$ cycles
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (LRN)\color{blue}{(BCG)}(KDFQVEO)   \\
 (TXY)\color{blue}{(AUM)}(HJPSWIZ) 
\end{eqnarray*}
leading to tau and sigma
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tau   = (LT)(RX)(NY)\color{blue}{(BA)(CU)(GM)}(KH)(DJ)(FP)(QS)(VW)(EI)(OZ) \\
\sigma = (RT)(NX)(LY)\color{blue}{(CA)(GU)(BM)}(DH)(FJ)(QP)(VS)(EW)(OI)(KZ)
\end{eqnarray*}
And the second solution
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (LRN)\color{blue}{(AUM)}(KDFQVEO)   \\
 (BCG)\color{blue}{(TXY)}(HJPSWIZ) 
\end{eqnarray*}
leading to tau and sigma
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tau   = (LB)(RC)(NG)\color{blue}{(AT)(UX)(MY)}(KH)(DJ)(FP)(QS)(VW)(EI)(OZ) \\
\sigma = (RB)(NC)(LG)\color{blue}{(UT)(MX)(AY)}(DH)(FJ)(QP)(VS)(EW)(OI)(KZ)
\end{eqnarray*}